# two buttons by event trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I want to create buttons for   move to left and right 2D animation ( two buttons : button left and button right )

my c# script is:

```
private bool moveLeft;
    private bool moveRight;
    Animator animator;
    float forwardSpeed = 10f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        animator = this.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {    
        if (moveLeft == true) {
            this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (Vector2.left * forwardSpeed);
            animator.SetInteger ("Direction", 2);
        }
        if (moveLeft == false) {
            this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (Vector2.right * forwardSpeed);
            animator.SetInteger ("Direction", 4);
        }
    }
    public void MoveMeLeft()
    {
        moveLeft = true;
    }
    public void StopMeLeft ()
    {
        moveLeft = false;
    }
}
```

*

so it does event trigger so  do pointer down  but don`t return to pointer up when pointer is up....

Comment: where do you call `MoveMeLeft` and `StopMeLeft `

Comment: make sure position is not changing in any animation, since you are changing it in code (via rigidbody)

Comment: Maybe show where you set the PointerDown and PointerUp in Unity.